# Windows 10 Pro NT DISM Repair image error 0x800f0906

Tags: networking, dism

I have been having some issues with accessing websites lately. On random websites my web browsers is either giving met the err_connection_reset error or an SNI error. To fix this i tried doing the DISM repair image thing.

When running DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth I get:

```
    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.15063.0

    Image Version: 10.0.15063.0

    [==========================100.0%==========================] The component store is repairable.
    The operation completed successfully.
```

Then when I try to repair it with DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth I get:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.15063.0

Image Version: 10.0.15063.0

[===========================96.8%========================  ]
Error: 0x800f0906

The source files could not be downloaded.
Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077
```

I already tried running the network problem solver to fix this but it doesn't find a solution. I also tried running windows update multiple times but while it says that it fixes things it doesn't fix anything.

I haven't been able to find a CBS log but the dism log can be found 
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bD0VesgHAO6-Ni3G9cFVTviU0LIaf56h/view?usp=sharing)

I am really lost as to what this could be so any help would be appreciated. Note that this happens on all web browsers I have installed(Chrome and Edge).

EDIT: After being pointed to the ISO by @Rahmound I downloaded it and tried to run the scanhealth, this times with the following command Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:E:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /limitaccess. However I am now getting the error 0x800f081f which means the source files could not be found. I find this weird since I am(at least I think I am) pointing to the file. Does anyone have a clue as to what I am doing wrong? New dism log can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UYjm9dfiTrGBxVaewI_SxtSr9eQ01ZNX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: is this chrome specific error...do other browsers work ?? Did you try reinstalling chrome ?

Comment: Its not a chrome specific error it happens with all browsers on this pc. Sorry for not including it ill add it right now.

Comment: DISM will not fix Chrome issues.  The file cannot be viewed.  Provide the relevant information in the body of your question

Comment: The file is viewable now

Comment: You are going to need to download the ISO for the whatever version of Windows 10 you are using, mount the ISO, then use the mounted ISO as the source for the command.  "Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image." - Indicates that DISM was unable to find the WinPE image that would have been used to repair WinSxS.  Some of your Chrome problems might be related to the fact you are still running Windows 10 version 1703.

Comment: To be specific, you have to point to install.wim, in order for DISM to find the image you want to use to repair your installation.

Comment: CBS logs are in `windir/CBS/Logs/` by the way

Comment: @Ramhound this folder unfortunately does not exist on my pc

Comment: @Micha - The logs would just confirm that the component store (WinSxS) has a problem anyways.  The end result is you will have to point the DISM file to the install.wim on the ISO to the same version of Windows 10 you have installed (1703).

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a legal way to get this file?

Comment: There is a question dedicated with multiple answers on how to get a Windows 10 1703 ISO.  What research have you done?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for the laziness on my part. After some searching I found the correct ISO but a new error occurred. If you have time please take a look at the new dism log.

Comment: The ISO on your machine must be running the same image otherwise you will get 0x800f081f.    What version is on the disk?

Comment: The version on my computer is 10.0.15063.0 and so is the version of the ISO I downloaded